# std::string to int / double in one pass

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11, std

I'm parsing a string which may contain either a real or an integral value. I would like to parse that string and get either the integral or the real value in a single parsing.

I could use std::stoi and std::stod, but if i call stoi first and it is a real, then it's going to fail and i will have to call stof, causing a second parsing. And if i call stof first and that the string contains an integral, it's going to consider it as a valid real value, losing the information that it is an integral.

Is there some kind of function that can parse both types in a single pass ? Or do i first have to look for a dot manually and call the right function ?

Thank you. :)

Comment: how about istringstream?

Comment: By curiosity, why do you want to make this distinction ?

Comment: Is the real guaranteed to be of `x.y` notation? Because there are plenty other notations (including but not limited to hexadecimal) that you could be required to read / parse, making a check for a dot fragile.

Comment: Because i'm tokenizing a string, and there can be litteral value tokens constructed using either an integral or a real. Right now I can't think of a reason why i would mix both.
@DevSolar It's ok if it only handles dot notation, i'm trying to write a simple script parser. I don't need anything too advanced.

Comment: I see, the "Pascal" way of typing string literals. This can come "for free" with a parser if it remembers having seen a dot or not. https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs331/notes/Pascal4.gif

Comment: @Virus721: Generally speaking, there's no such thing as a "simple" script parser, especially not if done procedurally and required to handle bad input gracefully. ;-) You might want to have a look at [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), which is simple enough to start with, and scales quite beautifully with your requirements. Totally worth the effort.

Comment: 8589934592 (2^33) is another, simpler case where you probably need `std::stod` yet there's no dot in the input.

Comment: @devsolar Thanks but i'm doing this in order to do it myself. I don't want a library to do the work for me.

Comment: @Virus721: That's a very bad habit to get into. The very idea of programming *is* to have a library doing the work for you. Consider common libraries to be *part* of the language. [Boost](http://www.boost.org) and [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) are my personal *minimum* of extensions. I don't want to "practice" UTF-8 parsing or reference-counting shared pointers either... ;-) Anyway, I was just sayin'. That's why I kept this comment, not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find a standard call to achieve this for the simple reason that a string of digits without a dot is both a valid integer and a valid double.

If your criterion is "double if and only if dot", then look for the dot by hand. Alternatively, read as double and check that the fractional part is null.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you mean something like : `is int if floor( float value ) == float value` ?

Comment: Yes, that's a way. If I were to do it, I would favor the dot search.

Comment: Searching for a dot seems longer and loses the possibility of using other notations, so why would you choose this instead ?

Comment: "seems longer": unsure, a call to floor and possible following cast to int do not come for free, on the opposite. "other notations": What about 2.25e2, which will be seen as an integer ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said (in the comments above) that simple dot notation is all you want in real numbers, and you want a single-pass (i.e. no back-stepping to already-parsed input), and (again from your comment) are more after the programming experience than efficiency / maintainability / extendability, how about this:

```
char const * input = /*...*/;
char const * parse_end;
size_t pos;
size_t pos2 = 0;

// parse integer (or pre-digit part of real)
int integer = strtol( input, &parse_end, 10 );

if ( *parse_end == '.' )
{
    // you have a real number -- parse the post-digit part
    input = parse_end;
    double real = strtod( input, &parse_end );
    // real + integer is your result
}
else
{
    // integer is your result
}

// in either case, parse_end is your position
```

Why did I use C functions... `stoi` returns an *index*, but `stod` expects a `string`. So I'd have to do a `substr()` or similar, while the C functions work with pointers, making things easier.

What I said in my comment holds true: As a brain experiment this holds some value, but any *real* parsing work should make use of existing solutions like [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html). Getting familiar with such building blocks is, IMHO, *more* valuable than learning how to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse it by yourself, using `std::string::substr`, `std::string::find_first_of`, `std::string::find_first_not_of`, etc.

As you know, each of `std::stoi` and `std::stof` interprets the first longest substring matching a right representation pattern of required type. You might think the integral-parsed result is always different real-parsed result if both possible, but it isn't.

Example 1: think about `"123."`. `std::stoi` will parse the substring `"123"` and `std::stof` will parse the whole `"123."`. `"123."` is a valid floating-point literal, but it represents an exact integer.

Example 2: think about `"123.0"`. This is a trivial real value representation. `std::stoi` will parse the substring `"123"` and `std::stof` will parse the whole `"123.0"`. Two results evaluate arithmetically same.

This is where you should decide what to parse and what not to. Please see cppreference.com article [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [floating-point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) for possible patterns.

With this difficulties, many lexers just tokenize the input (separating it by spaces) and check if the full token matches any of valid representation. **I think, If you don't know whether the input is integral or approx real, just parse it by std::stof.**

In addition, some solutions casting `float` to `int` would cause an erroneous behavior. A `float` typed variable having integral value is not guaranteed to be evaluated equal to an `int` typed variable with the same integral value. It's because `float`, commonly compiled to use `float32_t`(IEEE 754-1985 single / IEEE 754-2008 binary32) has 24 bits width of significand. So a valid string representation of integer which fits in 32-bit signed, may not fit in float. You lose the precision. `double`, commonly IEEE 754-2008 binary64, will not lose significand width compared with int32_t, but same problem with int64_t and so on.